# Group Addon causes Input to Lose Round Edges on Right Side

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

When using an input-group-addon (twitter bootsrap css) in a horizontal form layout the input loses the right hand side edge which becomes square instead of the normal nice round edges.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Date" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <input asp-for="Authoriser" class="form-control" />
      <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <label asp-for="AircraftID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span></span>
        <select asp-for="AircraftID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AircraftID"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="AircraftID" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/knju0sb0/

Comment: overwrite with a custom style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what is this element used for

```
 <span asp-validation-for="AircraftID" class="text-danger"></span>
```

but this is making the issue. place it outside its div.input-group ,(if possible) to achive rounded corners.

or else override with custom style

hope this helps..

Comment: Damn, so easy.  I just never thought of the validation being the problem.  Thanks.